# Tabs interactive dynamic tab styling

Tags: tailwind-css, flowbite

I am using flowbite / tailwind tabs interactive and the tab display functionality is working as expected. I would expect though that if you click on a new tab the old tab (bg-color) would become inactive and the new tab (bg-color) would be active(dark) for each tab.

What is happening is the profile tab loads  active with a (active)dark background. When you roll over the dashboard tab it highlights as it should (dark background) but when you click dashboard tab the Profile tab stays bg-color dark/active, the dashboard text becomes active but the bg-color of the dashboard tab does not change to active(darker color).

```
   'use client'
    import Image from 'next/image';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import { initFlowbite} from 'flowbite';

    export default function Winners() { 
        useEffect(() => {
                initFlowbite();
            return () => {            
            };
        }, []); 


        
    return ( 
        <>
    <ul className="flex flex-wrap text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400"
        id="default-tab"
        data-tabs-toggle="#default-tab-content" 
        role="tablist">
        <li className="me-2">
            <button  
                aria-current="page" 
                className="inline-block p-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-200 rounded-t-lg 
                dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-blue-500"
                id="profileTab" 
                data-tabs-target="#profile" type="button" 
                role="tab" aria-controls="profile" 
                aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
        </li>
        <li className="me-2">
            <button
                className="inline-block p-4 rounded-t-lg 
                hover:text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 
                dark:hover:text-gray-300"
                id="dashboard-tab" 
                data-tabs-target="#dashboard" type="button" 
                role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" 
                aria-selected="false">Dashboard</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="default-tab-content">
        <div className="hidden px-2 md:px-4 rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800" 
                id="profile" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="profileTab">
            <p className=" text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                theis is the provile tabe</p>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden px-2 md:px-4 rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800" 
                id="dashboard" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="dashboard-tab">
            <p className="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            dashbord sdfsdf sdfsdfs ssdsfsdfsdfsdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </>
    )
    }
```

I have tried focus:bg-black for testing which does work but on the initial load of the page the profile background color is not dark as it should be.

I have also tried data-active-classes="bg-black" the data active classes have absolutely no effect when placed in the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Flowbite's documentation](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/tabs/#customize-active-tab):

> ### Customize active tab
>
> You can use the `aria-selected:{class}` selector to style the currently active tab button element.

Thus, you could consider reworking your classes to have the active classes with `aria-selected:`, like:

```js
const { useEffect, useRef } = React;

function Winners() {
  useEffect(() => {
    initFlowbite();
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ul
        className="flex flex-wrap text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400"
        id="default-tab"
        data-tabs-toggle="#default-tab-content"
        role="tablist"
      >
        <li className="me-2">
          <button
            aria-current="page"
            className="inline-block p-4 rounded-t-lg
              hover:text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-200
              dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-300
              aria-selected:text-blue-600 aria-selected:bg-gray-200 
              dark:aria-selected:bg-gray-800 dark:aria-selected:text-blue-500"
            id="profileTab"
            data-tabs-target="#profile"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="profile"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Profile
          </button>
        </li>
        <li className="me-2">
          <button
            className="inline-block p-4 rounded-t-lg
              hover:text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-200
              dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-300
              aria-selected:text-blue-600 aria-selected:bg-gray-200 
              dark:aria-selected:bg-gray-800 dark:aria-selected:text-blue-500"
            id="dashboard-tab"
            data-tabs-target="#dashboard"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="dashboard"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Dashboard
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="default-tab-content">
        <div
          className="hidden px-2 md:px-4 rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800"
          id="profile"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="profileTab"
        >
          <p className=" text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            theis is the provile tabe
          </p>
        </div>
        <div
          className="hidden px-2 md:px-4 rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800"
          id="dashboard"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="dashboard-tab"
        >
          <p className="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            dashbord sdfsdf sdfsdfs ssdsfsdfsdfsdf
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<Winners />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.js" integrity="sha512-khqZ6XB3gzYqfJvXI2qevflbsTvd+aSpMkOVQUvXKyhRgEdORMefo3nNOvCM8584/mUoq/oBG3Vb3gfGzwQgkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```